# Automatically generate TeX to solve equation

Tags: math-mode, equations, latexalpha2

I am using LaTeX to show the solution to some equations which requires a lot of tedious and repetitive changing of terms. There are plenty of online solvers that can actually solve the equations themselves. However, are there any tools (packages or otherwise) that take TeX equations as input, parse and solve them, and then output the step-by-step solution as TeX?

For example, if I give it the following input:

```
\[ \frac{x^2}{2} = 1 \]
```

I would like it to return

```
\[ x^2 = 2 \]
\[ x = \sqrt{2} \]
```

Comment: TeX is for presenting your data and results. It was not invented to make you, as the author, obsolete.

Comment: Solving and typesetting a series of equations are two rather separate endeavors. TeX and friends are planted firmly on the typesetting side.

Comment: I understand. I didn't mean to restrict the tools to the TeX ecosystem - any kind of solution would do.

Comment: The [sagetex](https://ctan.org/pkg/sagetex) package lets you work with computer algebra system [SAGE](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/a_tour_of_sage/index.html) to solve such problems. You'd have to give the steps, such as in my answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136514/how-to-just-print-the-calculation-using-sagetex/136579#136579). With many cases, you could define a function to automate the process such as I did [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/500019/filling-the-latex-table-dynamically/500087#500087). SAGE isn't part of LaTeX. Use Cocalc to get started.

Comment: No, the last line of the result would be `$$ x = \pm \sqrt2 $$`. Note the `\pm`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution exists :-) but for me it is necessary one year :-)...before to understand and to build a code. You can try to use the `calculator` and `calculus` packages ([see pag. 24](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/calculator/calculator.pdf)).

I have only copy and past the code of the page 26 as example. For my humble opinion it is not very easy.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{calculator,calculus}

\begin{document}
% exp(-t)
\SCALEVARIABLEfunction
{-1}{\EXPfunction}
{\NEGEXPfunction}
% exp(-t)cos(t)
\PRODUCTfunction
{\NEGEXPfunction}
{\COSfunction}
{\NEGEXPCOSfunction}
% 3t^2-2exp(-t)cos(t)
\LINEARCOMBINATIONfunction
{3}{\SQUAREfunction}
{-2}{\NEGEXPCOSfunction}
{\myfunction}
\myfunction{5}{\sol}{\Dsol}
If
\[
f(t)=3t^2-2\mathrm{e}^{-t}\cos t
\]
then
\[
\begin{gathered}
f(5)=\sol\\
f'(5)=\Dsol
\end{gathered}
\]


\end{document}
```

### ADDENDUM:

If you use Mathematica 12, exist a package called [latexalpha2](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/latexalpha2/latexalpha2.pdf) that execute the Wolfram Language (Mathematica) source codes in a `LaTeX` document. For example to pag. 4 there is a step to solve an equation of second degree.

[image]

Comment: Sorry about the late response. I don't have Mathematica but that looks like a simple, elegant solution!

Comment: @sloth Ah, don't worry...I have forgot my old question :-) that I give you..ahahahh. All the best.

Answer (score 2):

A solution with Mathematica (not PSTricks) only for either fun or comparison purposes.

```mathematica
nEqns = 250;
coeffs = {};
While[Length[coeffs] < nEqns, 
 candidate = {#1 #3, #2 #3 + #1 #4, #2 #4} & @@ 
   RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, 4];
 acceptable = (Not[MemberQ[coeffs, #]] && First[#] != 0 && 
      GCD @@ # == 1) &@candidate;
 If[acceptable, AppendTo[coeffs, candidate]];]

({x^2, x, 1}.# == 0) & /@ coeffs // TableForm // TeXForm
```

## Output

All equations below can be factorized.

```
\begin{array}{c}
 -72 x^2+35 x+50=0 \\
 21 x^2+50 x+25=0 \\
 -x^2-19 x-90=0 \\
 70 x^2-33 x-4=0 \\
 14 x^2-19 x-3=0 \\
 60 x^2+32 x-7=0 \\
 -63 x^2-47 x+6=0 \\
 80 x^2+122 x+45=0 \\
 2 x^2+x-36=0 \\
 -4 x^2+49 x-90=0 \\
 21 x^2-52 x+7=0 \\
 35 x^2-18 x-81=0 \\
 -7 x^2+65 x-72=0 \\
 -21 x^2-79 x-30=0 \\
 42 x^2+13 x+1=0 \\
 36 x^2-77 x+40=0 \\
 10 x^2-79 x+63=0 \\
 5 x^2+31 x+6=0 \\
 -35 x^2+31 x-6=0 \\
 -10 x^2-31 x+63=0 \\
 27 x^2+102 x+40=0 \\
 6 x^2+23 x-35=0 \\
 -12 x^2+8 x-1=0 \\
 x^2+8 x+16=0 \\
 70 x^2+43 x-5=0 \\
 -50 x^2-55 x-14=0 \\
 7 x^2-15 x+8=0 \\
 -8 x^2+61 x-35=0 \\
 -35 x^2+58 x+9=0 \\
 -30 x^2-47 x+5=0 \\
 -10 x^2+101 x-10=0 \\
 35 x^2+82 x+48=0 \\
 9 x^2-9 x-40=0 \\
 -7 x^2-16 x+15=0 \\
 -6 x^2-5 x+4=0 \\
 -30 x^2+19 x+63=0 \\
 5 x^2+8 x-21=0 \\
 -10 x^2-29 x-18=0 \\
 -7 x^2+26 x-15=0 \\
 -x^2+x+20=0 \\
 2 x^2+7 x+5=0 \\
 -9 x^2-26 x-16=0 \\
 x^2+14 x+45=0 \\
 -2 x^2+11 x+63=0 \\
 -21 x^2-40 x+100=0 \\
 -8 x^2-79 x+10=0 \\
 10 x^2+79 x-8=0 \\
 7 x^2+52 x-32=0 \\
 -72 x^2+5 x+25=0 \\
 6 x^2-7 x-20=0 \\
 -18 x^2+39 x-20=0 \\
 -30 x^2-23 x+45=0 \\
 15 x^2-44 x-20=0 \\
 8 x^2+x-7=0 \\
 7 x^2+x-8=0 \\
 -21 x^2+67 x+10=0 \\
 63 x^2+58 x-16=0 \\
 -15 x^2-56 x-49=0 \\
 -36 x^2-48 x-7=0 \\
 x^2+9 x+18=0 \\
 -49 x^2+42 x+27=0 \\
 -2 x^2+15 x-27=0 \\
 6 x^2-37 x+56=0 \\
 6 x^2+41 x+30=0 \\
 -9 x^2+73 x-70=0 \\
 -10 x^2+17 x-3=0 \\
 -10 x^2-29 x+72=0 \\
 5 x^2-48 x+27=0 \\
 25 x^2+10 x-48=0 \\
 7 x^2+6 x-1=0 \\
 x^2+6 x-7=0 \\
 7 x^2-52 x+21=0 \\
 -4 x^2+45 x-50=0 \\
 16 x^2-34 x+15=0 \\
 -63 x^2-23 x+56=0 \\
 -3 x^2+2 x+1=0 \\
 28 x^2-39 x+5=0 \\
 90 x^2+31 x-4=0 \\
 -5 x^2-23 x-12=0 \\
 9 x^2-15 x-14=0 \\
 -21 x^2-5 x+4=0 \\
 100 x^2-80 x+7=0 \\
 -70 x^2+11 x+3=0 \\
 -35 x^2-38 x+9=0 \\
 -63 x^2-46 x-8=0 \\
 3 x^2-31 x+70=0 \\
 20 x^2-7 x-6=0 \\
 -10 x^2+31 x+63=0 \\
 -16 x^2-8 x+35=0 \\
 -20 x^2-27 x-9=0 \\
 18 x^2+21 x-49=0 \\
 -3 x^2+5 x+12=0 \\
 7 x^2+8 x+1=0 \\
 -20 x^2+27 x+8=0 \\
 -63 x^2+76 x+20=0 \\
 70 x^2+11 x-3=0 \\
 -9 x^2-41 x+20=0 \\
 -63 x^2-8 x+16=0 \\
 -4 x^2-19 x+5=0 \\
 50 x^2-45 x+9=0 \\
 10 x^2+19 x+7=0 \\
 -5 x^2+11 x+36=0 \\
 4 x^2-17 x-15=0 \\
 18 x^2+7 x-8=0 \\
 70 x^2+139 x+63=0 \\
 -14 x^2-43 x+90=0 \\
 2 x^2+x-10=0 \\
 10 x^2-7 x-6=0 \\
 -36 x^2-85 x-9=0 \\
 70 x^2+39 x-7=0 \\
 18 x^2+39 x-7=0 \\
 2 x^2-5 x+3=0 \\
 -72 x^2-13 x+20=0 \\
 -7 x^2-45 x-18=0 \\
 -12 x^2+16 x-5=0 \\
 8 x^2+13 x-6=0 \\
 -7 x^2-24 x-20=0 \\
 -24 x^2-58 x-35=0 \\
 -2 x^2+5 x-2=0 \\
 -35 x^2-17 x+36=0 \\
 -24 x^2-34 x-5=0 \\
 12 x^2+32 x+21=0 \\
 30 x^2-13 x+1=0 \\
 3 x^2+29 x-10=0 \\
 -35 x^2+34 x+21=0 \\
 12 x^2-55 x+50=0 \\
 21 x^2+44 x+15=0 \\
 30 x^2+29 x-35=0 \\
 8 x^2-13 x+5=0 \\
 -10 x^2-17 x+63=0 \\
 35 x^2+96 x+64=0 \\
 -30 x^2-89 x-24=0 \\
 18 x^2+51 x+8=0 \\
 -36 x^2-41 x-8=0 \\
 40 x^2-26 x-3=0 \\
 -8 x^2-39 x+54=0 \\
 14 x^2-33 x-56=0 \\
 -28 x^2+25 x+8=0 \\
 -30 x^2-47 x-14=0 \\
 -63 x^2-23 x-2=0 \\
 32 x^2+12 x-5=0 \\
 80 x^2-22 x-45=0 \\
 35 x^2+74 x+35=0 \\
 -3 x^2+40 x-100=0 \\
 6 x^2-17 x-28=0 \\
 -2 x^2-5 x+12=0 \\
 -4 x^2-16 x-15=0 \\
 6 x^2+x-7=0 \\
 -7 x^2-37 x-36=0 \\
 5 x^2+14 x+9=0 \\
 -21 x^2+x+2=0 \\
 18 x^2-29 x+10=0 \\
 -90 x^2-131 x-45=0 \\
 63 x^2-16 x+1=0 \\
 -24 x^2-59 x-7=0 \\
 45 x^2+61 x-36=0 \\
 4 x^2+11 x+6=0 \\
 7 x^2-19 x+10=0 \\
 -2 x^2+19 x-9=0 \\
 -40 x^2+51 x+7=0 \\
 -72 x^2+23 x+35=0 \\
 10 x^2-43 x+28=0 \\
 -7 x^2+66 x-27=0 \\
 -14 x^2-13 x+10=0 \\
 7 x^2-50 x+48=0 \\
 45 x^2+22 x-16=0 \\
 7 x^2-13 x+6=0 \\
 -36 x^2-59 x-24=0 \\
 -5 x^2-9 x+2=0 \\
 -3 x^2+29 x-18=0 \\
 20 x^2+24 x-9=0 \\
 -28 x^2-x+2=0 \\
 36 x^2+19 x-6=0 \\
 63 x^2+40 x-12=0 \\
 x^2-12 x+20=0 \\
 15 x^2-44 x+32=0 \\
 5 x^2+46 x+48=0 \\
 -4 x^2+x+18=0 \\
 -10 x^2-37 x-30=0 \\
 28 x^2-39 x-54=0 \\
 -x^2-2 x+8=0 \\
 -63 x^2+13 x+6=0 \\
 -9 x^2+11 x+14=0 \\
 -21 x^2-38 x-5=0 \\
 50 x^2-15 x-2=0 \\
 45 x^2-67 x-8=0 \\
 -5 x^2+59 x-90=0 \\
 32 x^2+12 x-27=0 \\
 12 x^2+8 x+1=0 \\
 -x^2-13 x-30=0 \\
 15 x^2+38 x+24=0 \\
 90 x^2+53 x-24=0 \\
 -6 x^2+13 x+15=0 \\
 30 x^2+103 x+10=0 \\
 -56 x^2+65 x-14=0 \\
 -6 x^2-35 x+49=0 \\
 42 x^2-19 x-35=0 \\
 -32 x^2+44 x+21=0 \\
 -16 x^2+40 x-21=0 \\
 6 x^2-59 x-10=0 \\
 9 x^2-100 x+100=0 \\
 7 x^2-30 x+8=0 \\
 -56 x^2-127 x-72=0 \\
 -15 x^2+67 x-72=0 \\
 25 x^2-90 x+81=0 \\
 x^2+11 x+30=0 \\
 30 x^2-71 x+42=0 \\
 -32 x^2+28 x+9=0 \\
 -7 x^2-4 x=0 \\
 -81 x^2-153 x-70=0 \\
 28 x^2+25 x-8=0 \\
 -4 x^2-29 x-30=0 \\
 14 x^2+29 x-15=0 \\
 54 x^2+57 x+10=0 \\
 -35 x^2+33 x+54=0 \\
 -24 x^2+10 x-1=0 \\
 -56 x^2+3 x+9=0 \\
 64 x^2-96 x+27=0 \\
 -2 x^2+25 x-72=0 \\
 50 x^2-65 x+6=0 \\
 -9 x^2-53 x-40=0 \\
 -3 x^2+14 x+80=0 \\
 -4 x^2+32 x-63=0 \\
 45 x^2-79 x+30=0 \\
 -25 x^2+20 x+21=0 \\
 -35 x^2+19 x+42=0 \\
 -15 x^2-46 x-16=0 \\
 -24 x^2-59 x+70=0 \\
 8 x^2+49 x+6=0 \\
 35 x^2+22 x-24=0 \\
 27 x^2-12 x-32=0 \\
 63 x^2+101 x+40=0 \\
 27 x^2+15 x-8=0 \\
 21 x^2+23 x-10=0 \\
 -8 x^2-87 x-70=0 \\
 4 x^2+31 x+21=0 \\
 5 x^2+34 x-7=0 \\
 -3 x^2+28 x-60=0 \\
 -8 x^2-26 x-21=0 \\
 21 x^2+38 x+5=0 \\
 63 x^2+146 x+80=0 \\
 -7 x^2+53 x+24=0 \\
 -40 x^2-29 x+18=0 \\
 28 x^2-15 x+2=0 \\
 -56 x^2-25 x+4=0 \\
 18 x^2-57 x-10=0 \\
 15 x^2+4 x-35=0 \\
 14 x^2+79 x+72=0 \\
 3 x^2-16 x+20=0 \\
 15 x^2-13 x-20=0 \\
\end{array}
```

Answer (score 1):

The package `latexalpha2`, as it is, requires  unix and `pdflatex`. It was adapted to windows and extended to lualatex. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/579254/161015
for a complete answer.

[image: xx]

Note. Wolfram Engine must be installed and wolframscript must be fully working on the command prompt!

> WolframScript enables Wolfram Language code to be run from any
> terminal, whether or not a Wolfram kernel is available on the system.

It is free from

https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/